# How to Invalidate() a control in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

In windows forms I could call the `Invalidate()` of a control to force it to re draw itself.
I have widget in GTK#, how can I accomplish the same?

Win7+MonoDevelop(2.9.4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use QueueDraw () to redraw everything or QueueDrawArea() for a specific rectangle area.

Comment: @lupus Forgive me for bringing up an old question but how do I force a `Draw()`? This does something similar to `Invalidate()` in winforms. How do I achieve the equivalent of `Refresh()` in GTK#? Any help please?